# Integration involving square root function

Tags: integration

[image]

First , i multiply numerator and denominator by (2-x-x^2)^(1/2),

then I split the integral into 2 parts ,

using trig substitution , part 2 is easy to be integrated ..

but when I tried to integrate part 2 , I was completely stuck, I tried trig substitution and integration by parts but none worked

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I use Maple to help me with the integral and the answer contains hyperbolic tangent inverse functions.

Comment: Try setting $\sin\alpha = \frac23(x+\frac12)$ as you did, but then do the "universal trig substitution" $y=\tan\frac\alpha2$; the result will be an integral of a rational function, which you can do using partial fractions. I think it will be a little easier if you do integration by parts as the very first step, integrating $\frac1{x^2}$ and differentiating $\sqrt{2-x-x^2}$, and then doing these substitutions.

Comment: oh ！ I see ,great !thank you so much , Greg  I was misguided by the hint on the textbook

Comment: See [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).